# VSTS Web test plgins

Tags: testing, web, plugins

I have recorded a web test which has the extraction rules for gathering the random number dynamically generated on the page. Now, if I want to get the randomly generated dynamic numbers from the response & store it in database/CSV file. How can I do it?

I have also tried using the web test plug in but am a bit confused.